# Jquery Disable Selected Value in All Dropdown with Same Values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my Php code

```
<?php 
    $menu_items = $this->db->get('menu_items');
    $menuOptions ='<select class="item_id" name="item_id[]">';
    $menuOptions .='<option value="">-- Select a Menu item --</option>';             
    foreach ($menu_items->result() as $row) {
    $menuOptions.= '<option value="'.$row->code.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
}
       $menuOptions.='</select>';
 ?>
```

I will echo this $menuOptions string to display select box with same values , i am having more than 10 select boxes in same page with same values

if i selected a value in one dropdown, the value should disabled in all 10 select boxes in that page

Here is the code which i tried but seems to be not fetching the value from second select box, it is fetching only the first select box selected value as because of class name is same,

```
$(".item_id").change(function () {
    var selected=$('.item_id option:selected').val();
    $('.item_id').each(function() {
    $('option[value="' + selected + '"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
  });
});
```

is there any way to disabled in jquery after it gets selected

Comment: Have you debugged already? Check what the selected variable is with console.log(). Also, your $('.item_id').each loop doesn't has any sense since the code in the loop isn't affected by the loop and you can put it outside the loop.

Comment: if i select a value in first drop down it shows the selected value in console, if i select the value in second drop down, it again shows the value of first drop down----------- I used each function to loop over all the .item_id class and add disabled attribute in options

Comment: "I used each function to loop over all the .item_id class and add disabled attribute in options" This is all true, but the loop still doesn't has any sense. You are changing the option to disabled in the loop, but you're not changing the option of the item in the loop to disabled, so the loop isn't necessary. You could do something like $(this).find('option') in the loop what would make the loop useful.

Comment: i tried of find also but seems to be not working so

Comment: Try debugging. Check what console_log('option[value="' + selected + '"]', $('option[value="' + selected + '"]') gives you

Comment: Nobody can debug these days

Comment: [option, option, prevObject: o.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "option[value="101"]", jquery: "2.1.0", constructor: function…] 

selector is "option[value="101"]"

Comment: change the line : var selected=$('.item_id option:selected').val(); to var selected=$(this).val();

Comment: Thank u vrajesh it didnt strikes my mind i done a very silly mistake any way thank u vrajesh

Comment: u welcome...musthafa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your answer:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xL8p478y/1/)

```js
$(".item_id").on('focus', function ()
  {
  // Store the current value on focus and on change
  previous = this.value;
  }).change(function() {
  // Do something with the previous value after the change  
  //alert(previous);
  var previoues_val=previous;//alert(p);
  var selected=$(this).val();
  var opts = $(this)[0].options;  
  var array = $.map(opts, function(elem) {
  return (elem.value || elem.text);
  });
  //alert(array);
  $('.item_id').each(function() {
   var v=$(this).val();
   if(previoues_val != '' )
   {
    //alert(p);
    $('option[value="' + previoues_val + '"]').removeAttr('disabled'); 
   }
  $('option[value="' + selected + '"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
  $('option[value=""]').removeAttr('disabled'); 
   });
  // Make sure the previous value is updated
  previous = this.value;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="item_id" name="item_id[]"><option value="">-- Select a Menu item --</option><option value="0">value0</option><option value="1">value1</option><option value="2">value2</option><option value="3">value3</option><option value="4">value4</option><option value="5">value5</option><option value="6">value6</option><option value="7">value7</option><option value="8">value8</option><option value="9">value9</option></select><select class="item_id" name="item_id[]"><option value="">-- Select a Menu item --</option><option value="0">value0</option><option value="1">value1</option><option value="2">value2</option><option value="3">value3</option><option value="4">value4</option><option value="5">value5</option><option value="6">value6</option><option value="7">value7</option><option value="8">value8</option><option value="9">value9</option></select><select class="item_id" name="item_id[]"><option value="">-- Select a Menu item --</option><option value="0">value0</option><option value="1">value1</option><option value="2">value2</option><option value="3">value3</option><option value="4">value4</option><option value="5">value5</option><option value="6">value6</option><option value="7">value7</option><option value="8">value8</option><option value="9">value9</option></select><select class="item_id" name="item_id[]"><option value="">-- Select a Menu item --</option><option value="0">value0</option><option value="1">value1</option><option value="2">value2</option><option value="3">value3</option><option value="4">value4</option><option value="5">value5</option><option value="6">value6</option><option value="7">value7</option><option value="8">value8</option><option value="9">value9</option></select>
```